# Getting cross streets from a geocoded address

Tags: iphone, geocoding, data-analysis

Let's say I have a lot of JSON data relating to intersections and their geolocations.

I have an app where the user uses his or her current location, and I want to be able to figure out what block they're on (i.e. the street they're on, and between what two cross streets). What's the best way to do this? Is there a good way?

Example: I get the user's geolocation, reverse-geocode it into 435 W. 42nd st. Using that data, I want to know that the user is between 9th ave and 10th ave on 42nd st.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the geolocations of each of the intersections, blocks or whatever you want to relate the user position to. Once you have that information, you can easily find the nearest intersections to the user's current geolocation.

If all of the geolocation information is in your JSON data, then work only in geolocations (don't reverse geocode) until you've determine the nearest intersections, etc.

You'll likely do best to convert your JSON data to a database so you can query more easily.

Comment: Sure, but what if it's an irregular street. For example, what if the user is right near one intersection, and far from the other cross street, and there's a closer intersection somewhere else than the one I'm looking for?

Comment: How does your geolocation JSON data represent streets? As a series of points or vectors?

Comment: Points. An example might be:
`{
"Street1":"42nd st",
"Street2":"9th ave",
"Latitude":*some number*,
"Longitude":*some number*}`

Comment: You'll need more than intersection data. You'll need actual street data or you won't be able to tell which street the user is on. With only intersection data, you might be able to tell the user where the nearest intersections are, but they may be intersections of streets that the user is not on. You have to have something that defines where the streets are.

Comment: I can get which street the user is on. The trick is finding the two intersections that bound the block the user is on. Does that make sense?

Comment: You'll need to have streets defined as a series of intersections, so you have the intersections in order.